# Access TortoiseSVN update text

Tags: tortoisesvn

When you use Tortoise SVN to update from the repository to your local machine, you get the popup that shows what files were added/updated/etc.  I'm looking to get hold of that text programmatically.

Do you know if it's dumped to a temporary file or a log file?  Or is there another way to get hold of that text?  I can't see anything in the settings that provides for it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the command line client?

Comment: I'm not a big fan of command line and the developers who will need my changes are generally using Tortoise.  Perhaps I could write an app that processes via the console and then integrate the app into the context menu.

Comment: Sorry, the word "programmatically" misguided me. I thought you wanted to automate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea might be to use the svn.exe console program, like this

```
svn.exe log -r head -v <svn-dir>
```

- -r means the revision (head being the newest)
- -v being verbose (which includes the file names)
- `<svn-dir>` is a dir that contains a svn checkout ( this can be omitted if you run the command inside such a dir).

There are also an -xml switch that might be useful if  you want to massage the data in some way

This requires that you have a `svn.exe` in you path. It seems to be possible to find the `svn.exe` exec. [here](http://alagazam.net/)

Comment: Does that actually run the update?  I am aware of the option of updating via console, but our developers are generally using Tortoise as its easier, less mental overhead.

Comment: It does not run the update, it is akin to choosing "Show log" from tort.svn.